# Bootstrap 3 code not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I uploaded a question that's the same as this one, however, that got very overcrowded so I am putting up the question again in hopes of explaining my problem a bit better.

I am currently making my own website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with bootstrap alongside. While trying to make the site mobile friendly, I have noticed an error with how 3 of the buttons are being displayed on the screen. Basically, what I want to happen is for the three buttons to be stacked on top of each other with a gap in between each one when the web page is viewed on mobile. However, the buttons aren't displaying correctly. See the first image.

One thing that I will say, though, is that I am using the feature (not sure if it's only in Google Chrome) that when you click inspect element, you can select an option that allows you to view what the web page will look like on a mobile screen. What I'm getting at, is that I don't know if it's the code that's wrong or if Google Chrome's feature doesn't work that well.

If you do have any suggestions for applications I could use to view the HTML file on a mobile device, please let me know.

***PLEASE NOTE. I HAVE ONLY GIVEN THE CODE FOR ONE OF THE BUTTONS AS THE OTHER TWO ARE BASICALLY THE SAME***

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .btn-block-xs {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

#cheapestOption {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border: none;
}

#cheapestOption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#cheapestOption p {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#cheapestOption ul{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#cheapestOption:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid" id="grad"> <!-- Pricing Buttons -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" id="cheapestOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align">
              <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
                <h4>Text</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £5 a month</span></p>
                <ul>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                </ul>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>
```

(First picture shows what it looks like on mobile) (this is what needs fixing)
(Second picture shows what it looks like on desktop) (this is fine)

[image: What it looks like on mobile]
[image: What it looks like on Desktop]

Comment: Can you show more of your HTML, of the parent container?

Comment: I suggest you make a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your code... This way one of us can easily show you exactly what to change. I would be happy to help. Let me know when you make the fiddle and provide the link.

Comment: @wuno https://jsfiddle.net/3nLptt77/1//

Comment: I get a 404 when I go to that link. The page does not exist.

Comment: @wuno https://jsfiddle.net/3nLptt77/ Sorry

Comment: So to clarify, You have all that text in 3 separate buttons and you want the text to be side by side? Do you mean the whole three red boxes be side by side? Or just the actual buttons? Also is there a reason you are putting the h4 and text inside the button? Would it make more sense to do 3 buttons with "submit" in them or something and then have the h4 above the buttons and text under it? You are not really doing this the "normal" way.

Comment: @wuno Ok, so basically the purpose of the buttons is to show the user the different plans we have available. They select which plan they would like to purchase by clicking on the button that represents the plan they want. Once they have clicked on the button, it takes them to a page with more information on that plan. If there is a more efficient way of doing that then please tell me. (1/2)

Comment: @wuno I want the buttons to be horizontal on the desktop version of the site and vertical on the mobile version with a gap in between each one. My problem can be seen in image one. They aren't formatting correctly. Now, I don't know if that is because there is something wrong in the code or if it's because the mobile emulator on Chrome isn't displaying it properly. The way it looks in the jsfiddle, is how it should look on the web page. Is there a way of me testing it on an actual mobile device maybe? (2/2)

Comment: I fixed it for you. Please see the jsfiddle in my answer. Also please review the changes I made to your code.

Comment: Ok I am sorry so you want them to stack on mobile. Do you know what browser width you want them to stack? I will update answer to help ya  bit more.

Comment: @wuno I would like the width of them to be 90% if that's what you mean.

Comment: Did you read all of my answer?

Comment: @wuno Yeah, sorry, I commented too early. This worked for me and it's now working as needed. Thanks alot.

Comment: No problem. I know it sounds repetitive and most people can be pretty cruel when you are learning. But bootstrap is VERY easy to use. Spend a night or two reading the docs and it will save you hours or days of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You html and css are not really following the bootstrap documentation. I suggest you read more on how bootstrap works. You can simplify a lot of what you are doing and probably make things look a lot better too.

I would suggest create a button which is a link and move the text out of it. To answer your question exactly please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytt7jcmv/).

I moved your html to be in the correct `col class` Let me know if you have anymore questions,

html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><button type="button" id="cheapestOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align">
          <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
            <h4>Text</h4>
            <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
            <ul>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
            </ul>
          </a>
        </button></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> <button type="button" id="averageOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align">
          <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
            <h4>Text</h4>
            <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
            <ul>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
              <li> Text </li>
            </ul>
          </a>
        </button></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> <button type="button" id="expensiveOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align" disabled>
          <h4>Text</h4>
          <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
          <p id="tempBottom"><strong>Coming Soon</strong></p>
        </button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

#cheapestOption {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
}

#cheapestOption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#cheapestOption p {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
   font-size: 1em;
}

#cheapestOption ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#cheapestOption:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#averageOption {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#averageOption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#averageOption p {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
   font-size: 1em;
}

#averageOption ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#averageOption:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

#expensiveOption {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#expensiveOption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#expensiveOption p {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#expensiveOption ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

To simplify this for you here are a few things to remember,

Bootstrap is built for mobile first. 
Each row consist of 12 pieces, so when you tell it col-md-4 you are saying that when the browser is the width of col-md you want that space to take up 1/3 of the width of the row.

You can target each browser size by default css built into bootstrap using col-xs col-sm -col-md etc... To see the default size of each col-size check the documentation or inspect element and check the class in the DOM.

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

If you want the col-size to stack at certain screen widths this is what you can do.

If when the screen is sm you want them to stack you could do,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
     <p>My text here will be on this row alone.</p>
   </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
     <p>My text here will be on this row alone.</p>
   </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
     <p>My text here will be on this row alone.</p>
   </div>
</div> <!-- end of row -->
```

This will stack on `sm` size because when the screen is the width of the sm size it will take up 12 which is the whole space. So that media query will fire off and the col will now take up the whole row.

Remeber you can stack each class as well. So if you want to make sure each col stack starting with md you could do this,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
```

Now when the browser is at each of those class target widths whatever html is in that div will take up the whole row.